# sqlite3 query for disk space usage

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a complex sqlite3 database that weighs several hundred megabytes, and I'd like to know where this space is taken.. which columns have on average the biggest fields, which records..

any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SQLite3 Analyzer from [the download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)